# Booked/paid for room, not available upon arrival

Tags: usa, bookings, hotels

**TL;DR:
Booked and paid for a room, room was not available, the hotel clerk said there was a room but that he chose not to give it to us, we ended up sleeping in the car. What is the best course of action?**

My partner and I booked a room in northern Georgia state near Chattanooga, TN for the long drive back from Florida to Michigan. The room was reserved and paid for through 3rd-party, Hotwire, the hotel chain was ChoiceHotels. (I've never before stayed there.)

We arrived in the mountain town and quickly learned that the hotel was overbooked and that the previous clerk had given our room to someone else. I asked for a manager as I assumed a manager would be able to do something such as offer up a not-so-great room that they don't normally rent out (maybe the air conditioner is in-service or something, I don't know.)

I stepped aside to contact Hotwire while my partner tried to come up with ideas with the clerk. As the clerk had not given out contact info for the manager, my partner asked him again to contact the manager. The clerk then said that he was going to give us a room, but now he's not and said something about being a man and not a little boy. He never contacted the manager nor gave us details to contact the manager.

Knowing I would likely receive a refund (I did), I looked for hotels in the area but there appeared to be some sports events and with spring break, absolutely nothing was available. The gentleman at Quality Inn did not offer any help. We continued to drive north hoping we could find a place to stay as we got further from Chattanooga but this was fruitless. We ended up sleeping in our car at a truck stop (note that my partner is in his 60s, so days later he is still hurting.)

What *should* the hotel chain have done in this case? What recourse should I expect?

Comment: Given that you got a refund (full?) I doubt that there is anything legal you can do.  On the other hand this is the sort of thing that is nightmares for the Hotels PR - especially with your partners age and ending up sleeping in your car.  You might do better to loudly complain on Twitter to their PR account

Comment: There's always small claims court, though this would be a better question for Law.SE

Comment: The clerk was going to give you a room, then not. Something changed, seemingly related to their interaction with your partner. Not saying you're to blame, am saying that something is missing in this story.

Comment: Over booking hotels isn't uncommon and usually works out OK because of cancellations. I've had it happen to me, and have had the hotel find me a room at another nearby. I got the room at the original price, and usually a discount or voucher for future stay. Occasionally, everything is booked and there's just nothing they can do. It sucks. You got your money back. Other than complain on social media, you just kinda move on...

Comment: @ugoren There was nothing odd about my partner’s exchange and we were respectful to the guy. I have no idea why he said that.

Comment: @MelanieShebel: You said that you "stepped aside" to contact Hotwire, which implies that you didn't witness the relevant exchange. Which probably involved your partner saying something like "Get me the manager, I need to talk to an adult!"

Comment: @TonyK I witnessed the exchange; I stepped away from the front of the desk to the side as to not block him from helping others while I awaited support from Hotwire.